# UITableview with static cells - label text doesn't show up before I tap on cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a table with static cells. I also have a button that sets the textLabel.text property for each of the cells.

When i press that button, nothing happens visually, even though the labels were really changed.

And here's the weird thing: If i tap on the cell, the value suddenly shows. So i have to tap on each cell to reveal the label text. Now I can tap on the button again (which changes the labels), and it will work fine - I only need to tap the cells the first time, and then they stay "activated".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `[cell setNeedsLayout]` after you change the text. The cell will size its label to `CGSizeZero` in `layoutSubviews` if its `textLabel`'s `text` is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But Is there any way I can do this on ALL cells in the entire tableview?

Comment: Found the solution for previous question myself:  
      
        NSArray *cells = [myTableView visibleCells];  
          
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)  
        {  
            [cell setNeedsLayout];  
        }

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! I didn't read close and didn't realize you were talking about multiple cells :)